# refresh data in data table on another form after updating database on another form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datatable

I have 2 forms `Form1` and `Form2`. `Form1` has the `DataTable` on it which is connected to a `MySql` database. I create a new call on `Form1` which then opens up `Form2` where there are some fields to fill in. I then press save call and this updates the databse.

The problem I have is when it saves to the database and I close `Form2` It hasn't showed up on `Form1` unless I close the program and re open it. How do I get the `DataTable` to refresh?

Here is the `Form1` code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;database=***;username=***;password=***;";
            string query = "select call_ref, opened, contact, it, summary  from helpdesks;";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dTable);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
            connection.Close();
        }

        public void viewData(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
            secondForm.Show();

            string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;***;username=***;password=***;";
            string query = "select * from users where id = " + this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value + ";";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();

            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                secondForm.textBox1.Text = reader.GetString("call_ref");
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        private void newCallBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
            secondForm.Show();
        }
    }
```

And this is my `Form2` code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void saveCallBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;database=***;username=***;password=***;";
            string query = "INSERT INTO helpdesks(contact, opened)VALUES('" + textBox2.Text + "',STR_TO_DATE('" + DateTime.Now + "','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'));";
            MySqlConnection connection = new     MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Call Saved");
            connection.Close();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use FormClosedEventArgs.

```
private void newCallBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
            secondForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form2_Closed);
            secondForm.Show();
        }
```

In Form1 add:

```
private void Form2_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
          // here update DataTable

        }
```

Comment: You could do that by using your code:             string connectionString = "datasource=localhost;database=***;username=***;password=***;";
            string query = "select call_ref, opened, contact, it, summary  from helpdesks;";...

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't update the table in form1 unless I close form1 and re open it, it's doing the same as it was before, except updating when I close form2 instead of pressing save call.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. You just said it works when you reopen form1, why don't you call same method as you call when you are loading form1?

Comment: form1 stays open behind form2, so can I call the same method I do on form 1 as I close form 2?

Comment: Yes, do it in the place i left comment (//here update DataTable)